# I need winning combinations for Tic Tac Toe (or at least some hints/tips)

Tags: python, python-3.x, tic-tac-toe

For a class project, my groupmates and I are to code a tic tac toe program. So far, this is what we have. All of us have 0 experience in python and this is our first time actually coding in python.

```
import random
import colorama 
from colorama import Fore, Style 
print(Fore.LIGHTWHITE_EX + "Tic Tac Toe - Below is the key to the board.") 

Style.RESET_ALL 

player_1_pick = ""
player_2_pick = "" 

if (player_1_pick == "" or player_2_pick == ""):
  if (player_1_pick == ""):
    player_1_pick = "Player 1"
  if (player_2_pick == ""):
    player_2_pick = "Player 2"
else:
  pass

board = ["_"] * 9 

print(Fore.LIGHTBLUE_EX + "0|1|2\n3|4|5\n6|7|8\n") 

def print_board():
  for i in range(0, 3):
    for j in range(0, 3):
      if (board[i*3 + j] == 'X'):
        print(Fore.RED + board[i*3 + j], end = '') 
      elif (board[i*3 + j] == 'O'):
        print(Fore.BLUE + board[i*3 + j], end = '') 
      else:
        print(board[i*3 + j], end = '') 

      print(Style.RESET_ALL, end = '') 

      if j != 2:
        print('|', end = '') 

    print() 

print_board() 

while True:
  x = input('Player 1, pick a number from 0-8: ') #
  x = int(x)
  board[x] = 'X' 
  print_board()  
  o = input('Player 2, pick a number from 0-8:') 
  o = int(o)
  board[o] = 'O' 
  print_board() 

answer = raw_input("Would you like to play it again?") 
if answer == 'yes': 
  restart_game()     
else:
  close_game() 

WAYS_T0_WIN = ((0,1,2)(3,4,5)(6,7,8)(0,3,6)(1,4,7)(2,5,8)(0,4,8)(2,4,6))
```

We're stuck on how to have the program detect when someone has won the game and then have it print "You won!" and also having the program detect when it's a tie and print "It's a tie!". We've looked all over the internet for a solution but none of them work and we can't understand the instructions. No use asking the teacher because they don't know python or how to code.

Comment: well once you work out the win condition a tie is easy, if the person who just played didnt win and the board has no more spaces then its a tie. For the win condition you need to check for 3 of the same token in a row, that could be on any row, column or diagonal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have changed your code in such a way that first of all "save players choices" and in second "check if a player won and break the loop":

```
import random
import colorama 
from colorama import Fore, Style 
print(Fore.LIGHTWHITE_EX + "Tic Tac Toe - Below is the key to the board.") 

Style.RESET_ALL 

player_1_pick = ""
player_2_pick = "" 

if (player_1_pick == "" or player_2_pick == ""):
    if (player_1_pick == ""):
        player_1_pick = "Player 1"
    if (player_2_pick == ""):
        player_2_pick = "Player 2"
else:
    pass

board = ["_"] * 9 

print(Fore.LIGHTBLUE_EX + "0|1|2\n3|4|5\n6|7|8\n") 

def print_board():
    for i in range(0, 3):
        for j in range(0, 3):
            if (board[i*3 + j] == 'X'):
                print(Fore.RED + board[i*3 + j], end = '') 
            elif (board[i*3 + j] == 'O'):
                print(Fore.BLUE + board[i*3 + j], end = '') 
            else:
                print(board[i*3 + j], end = '') 

            print(Style.RESET_ALL, end = '') 

            if j != 2:
                print('|', end = '') 

        print() 


def won(choices):
    WAYS_T0_WIN = [(0,1,2), (3,4,5), (6,7,8), (0,3,6), (1,4,7), (2,5,8), (0,4,8), (2,4,6)]
    for tpl in WAYS_T0_WIN:
        if all(e in choices for e in tpl):
            return True
    return False

print_board()


turn = True
first_player_choices = []
second_player_choices = []

while True:
    if turn:
        x = input('Player 1, pick a number from 0-8: ') #
        x = int(x)
        if board[x] == '_':
            board[x] = 'X'
            first_player_choices.append(x)
            turn = not turn
            print_board()
            if won(first_player_choices):
                print('Player 1 won!')
                break
        else:
            print('Already taken! Again:')
            continue
    else:
        o = input('Player 2, pick a number from 0-8: ') #
        o = int(o)
        if board[o] == '_':
            board[o] = 'O'
            second_player_choices.append(o)
            turn = not turn
            print_board()
            if won(second_player_choices):
                print('Player 2 won!')
                break
        else:
            print('Already taken! Again:')
            continue


# answer = input("Would you like to play it again?") 
# if answer == 'yes': 
#     restart_game()     
# else:
#     close_game()
```

I also added a condition to check if players choice is already taken! By the way, you can do it way much better. :)

**EDIT:** there was a little problem with spaces in my answer here and I solve it in edit. Now you can directly copy it in a py file and run it!

Answer (score -1):

Firstly, you need a condition which doesn't allow the same space to be allocated twice, when test running I could type space 3 as much as I wanted for example without it stopping me. You need some sort of check for this.

Secondly, for the actual win system, you made it easy because you already have the co-ordinates for all of the winning games, I recommend something along the lines of:

```
def checkwin(team):
  for i in WAYS_TO_WIN:
    checked = False
    while not checked:
      k = 0
      for j in i:
        if board[j] == team:
          k+=1
        if k == 3:
          return True
          checked = True
```

This way is checks if any of the co-ordinates have all 3 of any set. You might have to adjust this code, but this looks like a solution.

Note: I'm still a beginner at coding and I stumbled upon your thread, this is an idea not necessarily a working solution